# Having trouble with passing array of pointers to functions to other functions

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error:

```
error C2664: 'KaibaMainPhase' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
'void (__cdecl *[2])(std::vector<_Ty> &,
std::vector<_Ty>&,
std::vector<std::vector<_Ty>> &,
std::vector<_Ty> &,std::vector<_Ty> &)'
to 'void (__cdecl *)(std::vector<_Ty> &,
std::vector<Card> &,
std::vector<Card> &)"
```

Here's my code:

```
class Card
{
public:
string GetName() {return Name;}
void SetName(const string& setName) {Name = setName; } 
void SetType(const string& setType) {Type = setType; }

private:
string Name;
string Type;
};

vector< vector<Card> > Field(4, vector<Card>(5));
vector<Card> KaibaHand;
vector<Card>::iterator KH;
vector<Card> YugiHand;
vector<Card>::iterator YH;

vector<Card> KaibaGraveyard;
vector<Card>::iterator KG;
vector<Card> YugiGraveyard;
vector<Card>::iterator YG;


void KaibaBeginning(vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck);
void DrawForKaiba(vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck);
void KaibaMainPhase(void (*)(vector< vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard,
vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard), vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, vector<
vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard);


void FieldFunction(vector< vector<Card> > &Field);
void KaibaHandFunction(vector<Card> &KaibaHand);
void KaibaGraveyardFunction(vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard);
void YugiGraveyardFunction(vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard);
void KaibaSummon(vector< vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &KaibaHand, int HandNumber, int
MonstCount);
void YugiSummon(vector< vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &YugiHand, int HandNumber, int
MonstCount);
void KaibaDiscard(int HandNumber, vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard);
void YugiDiscard(int HandNumber, vector<Card> &YugiHand, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard);


void KaibaMainPhase(void (*)(vector< vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard,
vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard), vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck,
vector<vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard);


void HEAVYSTORM(vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, vector< vector<Card> > &Field,
vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard)
{
cout<<"This card destroys ALL magic and traps cards on the field!!"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        YugiGraveyard.push_back(Field[0][i]);
    Field[0][i]=Card();
        KaibaGraveyard.push_back(Field[3][i]);
        Field[3][i]=Card();
    }   
}

void POTOFGREED(vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, vector< vector<Card> > &Field,
vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard)
{
DrawForKaiba(KaibaHand, KaibaDeck);
}


int main()
{

void (* pFunct[2]) (vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, vector< vector<Card> >
&Field, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard);
pFunct[0] = HEAVYSTORM;
pFunct[1] = POTOFGREED;


KaibaMainPhase(pFunct, KaibaHand, KaibaDeck, Field, YugiGraveyard, KaibaGraveyard);
}


void KaibaMainPhase( void (*pFunct)(vector<Card> &KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, vector<
vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard), vector<Card>
&KaibaHand, vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, vector< vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard,
vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard)
{
int HandNum;
cout<<"Enter a number: "<<endl;
cin>>HandNum;
cout<<"You played "<<Field[3][HandNum-1].GetName();
pFunct[HandNum-1](KaibaHand, KaibaDeck, Field, KaibaGraveyard, YugiGraveyard);//
}

void KaibaHandFunction(vector<Card> &KaibaHand)
{
    cout<<endl<<"Kaiba's hand contains: "<<endl;
    for (KH=KaibaHand.begin(); KH<KaibaHand.end(); KH++)
    {
        cout<<KH->GetName()<<endl;

    }
}

void YugiHandFunction(vector<Card> &YugiHand)
{
    cout<<endl<<"Yugi's hand contains: "<<endl;
    for (YH=YugiHand.begin(); YH<YugiHand.end(); YH++)
    {
        cout<<YH->GetName()<<endl;

    }
}

void KaibaGraveyardFunction(vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard)
{
        cout<<endl<<"Kaiba's graveyard contains: "<<endl;
        for (KG=KaibaGraveyard.begin(); KG<KaibaGraveyard.end(); KG++)
        {
            cout<<KG->GetName()<<endl; //SAME AS (*gt).GetName
        }
        cout<<"\n";
}

void YugiGraveyardFunction(vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard)
{
        cout<<endl<<"Yugi's graveyard contains: "<<endl;
        for (YG=YugiGraveyard.begin(); YG<YugiGraveyard.end(); YG++)
        {
            cout<<YG->GetName()<<endl; //SAME AS (*gt).GetName
        }
        cout<<"\n";
```

Comment: Your error message should refer you to a specific line.   Please indicate which line.  Also, consider removing some of the unrelated code from the question, and *actually* asking a question.  I don't see any question here.  (hint: questions end with question-marks ??)

Comment: You know what `typedef` is and how to use it?

Comment: My condolences, this code looks impenetrable and unmaintainable. Best of luck. Perhaps start by breaking down things like `vector< vector<Card> > &Field` into their own classes and provide methods on them that do things that `Field` objects should do?

Answer (score 8):

In this line:

```
void KaibaMainPhase(void (*)(vector< vector<Card> > &Field, vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard, vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard), vect....
```

You declared that the first parameter to `KaibaMainPhase` will be a function of 3 parameters.

```
void KaibaMainPhase(
    /* Function Pointer */ void (*)(
    /* Param #1         */ vector< vector<Card> > &Field,
    /* Param #2         */ vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard,
    /* Param #3         */ vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard), /*other parameters to KaibaMainPhase*/....
```

Later on, in this code:

```
pFunct[0] = HEAVYSTORM;
[...]
KaibaMainPhase(pFunct, KaibaHand, Kaiba.....
```

You are passing `pFunct`, which is an array of two different functions.
An array is not the same as a function pointer.

But, even if you did pass `pFunct[0]`, it wouldn't work.
`pFunct` is declared to be an array of function pointers, where each function has **5** parameters:

```
/* Array of 2 fnct ptrs */ void (* pFunct[2])(
/* Param #1 */ vector<Card> &KaibaHand,
/* Param #2 */ vector<Card> &KaibaDeck,
/* Param #3 */ vector< vector<Card> > &Field,
/* Param #4 */ vector<Card> &KaibaGraveyard,
/* Param #5 */ vector<Card> &YugiGraveyard
);
```

But the function `KaibaMainPhase` is expecting a function that only takes **3** parameters.